# How to fill missing DataFrame value by copying a value from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Mick Jagger's last name is missing in a data. Only the fist name and the band's name were specified

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'fist': ['John', 'Mick'], 
                    'last':['Lennon', ''], 
                    'band':['Beatles', 'Rolling Stones'] })
```

I can easily assign a new value to the missing field with:

```
df['last'][df['last'] == ''] = 'Jagger'
```

But instead of assigning a new value 'Jagger' I would rather fill it by copying a value taken from the corresponding 'band' column. So the end result would look like:

```
             band  fist            last
0         Beatles  John          Lennon
1  Rolling Stones  Mick  Rolling Stones
```

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas.Series.where()` to conditionally replace values of the current Series with values from another Series:

```
df['last'].where(df['last'] != "", df.band)

#0            Lennon
#1    Rolling Stones
#Name: last, dtype: object

df['last'] = df['last'].where(df['last'] != "", df.band)
df

#   band            fist              last
#0  Beatles         John            Lennon
#1  Rolling Stones  Mick    Rolling Stones
```

Comment: Thanks for `df['last'] = df['last'].where(df['last'] != "", df.band)`

Answer (score 2):

a missing data would normally be a NaN values, not a string. So in the case that you have NaNs instead of '', you can actually pass another `column` to the `fillna()` method:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'fist': ['John', 'Mick'],
                    'last':['Lennon', np.nan],
                    'band':['Beatles', 'Rolling Stones'] })
In[37]: df
Out[37]: 
             band  fist    last
0         Beatles  John  Lennon
1  Rolling Stones  Mick     NaN
```

now with `fillna()`

```
df['last'].fillna(df.band, inplace=True)
df
Out[44]: 
             band  fist            last
0         Beatles  John          Lennon
1  Rolling Stones  Mick  Rolling Stones
```